# CoreData predicate: string property length?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

Say if I have an entity `Fragment`, it has an attribute 'text' which is a string, I want to query the list of `Fragment` whose `text` is of length 5:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"position == %@ AND text.length == %d", pos, 5];
```

It does not work (ie returns no result), but if I remove text.length in the query it works and I'm certain that there are texts of length 5, so what do I need to change it to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no length attribute for strings in the `NSPredicate`. Use regex instead. 
Your predicate should look as follows:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"position == %@ AND text MATCHES %@", pos, @".{5}"];
```

Comment: +1, MATCHES is nicer than LIKE because it is easier to modify for different lengths.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Objective-C functions like `length` in a Core Data fetch request. But you
can replace it with the "LIKE" operator, which does a simple pattern matching:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"text LIKE %@", @"?????"];
```

An interesting point is that Core Data does not throw an exception or return with an error,
but just ignores the `length` method, i.e. it just uses the predicate `"text = '5'` instead.
This can be seen by activating Core Data debug output by setting the launch argument

```
-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 3
```

(which is generally a good method to locate Core Data fetch problems).

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's taking text.lengh as a relationship. Try to set a predicate only with position and then do a loop looking for text.length == 5.