# NSPredicate to check for NULL, and blank strings in Core Data

Tags: core-data, ios7, nspredicate, nsexpression, predicatewithformat

As CoreData length is not supported and CoreData translates the predicate name.length > 1 to sqlite in name > 1... While it should be length(name) > 1.

We can use this one:
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT name MATCHES '^\s*$'"];

But regular expression will have a higher computation cost (takes longer than to evaluate a regex than simple equality).

SO how i have to do fetch.Any best idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please go through [CoreData predicate: string property length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19889211/coredata-predicate-string-property-length)

or you can do like this

```
NSString *attributeName = @"name";
NSString *attributeValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@".{%d}", 5];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K MATCHES %@", attributeName, attributeValue];
```

Reference - [NSPredicate for an NSManagedObject's string attribute's length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644621/nspredicate-for-an-nsmanagedobjects-string-attributes-length)

Comment: I donot want to check whether its length is greater than 5 or not. I just want to check if its length>0.